# How to use variable mongoose query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

data schema

```
ID: String,    
Item: {
       Possess: {
          Jewel: [Number]
     }
```

code

```
var temp = 1
db.collection.update({"ID":"sample"},{"$set":{"Item.Possess.Jewel.1":888})
```

How to use variable  temp  in "Item.Possess.Jewel.1" ?

"Item.Possess.Jewel.temp" doesn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to build up your `$set` object programmatically:

```
var temp = 1;
var set = {$set: {}};
set.$set["Item.Possess.Jewel." + temp] = 888;
db.collection.update({"ID":"sample"}, set);
```