# Mongoose schema, set key variable

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm using expressjs, mongodb and mongoose, I'm trying to update the counts object of the following schema:

```
var UsersSchema = new Schema({
  username: { type: String, required: true },
  counts: {
    followers: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    trips: { type: Number, default: 0 },
    videos: { type: Number, default: 0 }
  }
})
```

And the update part (not working):

```
var key = 'trips' // set dynamically, could be 'videos' or 'followers'
Users.update({'username': username}, {$set: {'counts.key': 12}}, callback)
```

Working example but not dynamic:

```
Users.update({'username': username}, {$set: {'counts.trips': 12}}, callback)
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use variable mongoose query?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21592595/how-to-use-variable-mongoose-query)

Comment: Yes, thanks! This is what I was looking for. I wonder if there are others ways to do that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create dynamic variable for $set and use in query.

```
var key = 'trips';
var dynSet = {$set: {}};
dynSet.$set["counts." + key] = 12;
Users.update({'username': username}, dynSet, callback)
```

Comment: This solution doesn't seem to work, but it looks much cleaner that way .

Comment: let me check one min .